# I can't load bootstrap to my form Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I can't load bootstrap sass to my form in users/new.html.erb 
In railstutorial.org in listing 7.15 / 7.16 it looks like this: 1`1
[image]

For me it looks like this:
[image]

My repository:
https://github.com/xt442/railstutorialorg

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to `wrap` the `label & text field` with the div with class `form-group`.
& for button to span over the entire width of the parent element use class `btn-block`

Something like following

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: 'form-group' do %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: 'form-group' do %>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: 'form-group' do %>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: 'form-group' do %>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it could fix, but I notice you've missed params partial:

```
<%= render partial:'layouts/header' %>
```

and

```
<%= render partial:'layouts/footer' %>
```

that should work